# Save Excel as HTML in Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to save an existing Excel file to HTML in Python using `win32com.client`. Below is my code and the resulting error message. Any suggestions?

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'D:\eclipse\test.xlsx')
excel.Visible = True
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ob = wb.PublishObjects.Add(1,'C:\test.html','Sheet1')
ob.Publish(True)
```

With the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "D:\eclipse\DMS\AGADMS\exceltohtml.py", line 21, in <module>  
ob = wb.PublishObjects.Add(1,'C:\test.html')  
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7\PublishObjects.py", line 37, in Add
    , Title)  
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'D:\eclipse\atest.xlsx')
excel.Visible = True
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
wb.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType=constants.xlSourceRange,Filename=r'D:\eclipse\atest1.html',Sheet='Sheet1',Source='$A$1:$F$6',HtmlType=constants.xlHtmlStatic, DivID='xxx1')
wb.PublishObjects(1).Publish(True)

Comment: using below code successfully save excel to html file. fyi.

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is very good for this.

Using pandas should simplify this for you. See below:

```
import pandas as pd 

wb = pd.read_excel('D:\eclipse\test.xlsx') # This reads in your excel doc as a pandas DataFrame

wb.to_html('C:\test.html') # Export the DataFrame (Excel doc) to an html file
```

Example Excel input:

[image]

Example html output:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what about images stored in the excel

Comment: This only saves dataframe. Not formatting and other info

Answer (score 0):

Use `xlsx2html` module which will retain the cell formatting information as well.
link:https://pypi.org/project/xlsx2html/