# How can I convert an Excel spreadsheet to HTML with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have several .xlsx Excel spreadsheets that I'd like to convert to an HTML web format by using a Python script. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Python with Pandas. Install Pandas by running `pip install pandas` from the terminal/command line.

Then run the following code to create a *spreadsheet.html* file from a *spreadsheet.xlsx* file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('spreadsheet.xlsx')
with open('spreadsheet.html', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(df.to_html())
```

Comment: Just a heads up, opening the file manually isn't required. Just hand `DataFrame.to_html()` the path to write to as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783671/12479639).